# What's the point in wrapping a function in a function type?

Tags: go

I am new to golang and I've seen occasionally some code that wraps a function inside a function type. In http package we have this as well:

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

I'm curious to know the reason behind. If we want to have a type that exposes a method why don't we create a struct type and add the method to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two main reasons:

1. Convenience when receiving functions as arguments:

   ```
    type LongFuncSig func(a int, b *int, c string, d *SomeWeirdThing, f map[string]*Foo, g ...interface{}) (*Result, error)

    func DoSomething(fn LongFuncSig) { ... }
    func DoSomethingElse(fn LongFuncSig) { ... }
    func DoYetAnotherThing(fn LongFuncSig) { ... }
   ```

   Is much more readable, and less error-prone than:

   ```
    func DoSomething(fn func(a int, b *int, c string, d *SomeWeirdThing, f map[string]*Foo, g ...interface{}) (*Result, error)) { ... }
    func DoSomethingElse(fn func(a int, b *int, c string, d *SomeWeirdThing, f map[string]*Foo, g ...interface{}) (*Result, error)) { ... }
    func DoYetAnotherThing(fn func(a int, b *int, c string, d *SomeWeirdThing, f map[string]*Foo, g ...interface{}) (*Result, error)) { ... }
   ```
2. When you want to attach methods to the type.

   In your example, `http.HandlerFunc` has an attached method, [`ServeHTTP`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP). This causes the function to satisfy the [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) interface. It's only possible to attach methods to named types.

And to answer your related question:

> If we want to have a type that exposes a method why don't we create a struct type and add the method to it?

Because there's no reason to do do that. The standard library *could* have chosen to take your suggestion with:

```
    type HandlerFunc struct {
        Func func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
    }
```

But that's far more verbose, and harder to use and read. To use that, you'd then have to call:

```
    http.HandlerFunc{Func: fn}
```

instead of the much simpler:

```
    http.HandlerFunc(fn)
```

So there's no reason to add unnecessary complexity.